# How to indicate some fields are not supported

Tags: java, time

Trying to move from Calendar to the new Java 8 time on Android. Is there a way to indicate that a time or date field is not supported? I can use the 'Truncate' method that will set all time fields of a shorter duration to zero, so a time stamp like 2020-09-30T10:37:15.345-04:00 can be truncated say at the minutes level. But that will leave 2020-09-30T10:00:00.00-04:00.

However, what I want to indicate is that the clock does not have minutes or less precision so that when one tries to read the minutes or seconds, there will be some indication that there are no such fields or that they are unknown. Zero is a valid value.

Right now in the Calendar case I have to add numerous methods to a class to indicate that. For example, I made a class called TimeStruct which wraps a Calendar. If I take a time stamp like 2020-10-01T04:55 it does not have minutes. So to keep that information I have a variable 'isSecondsSet' and set it to false. I create the Calendar from the elements I DO have. But as soon as I call something like Calendar.getTimeInMillis() the seconds and milliseconds fields get set to 0 and are indicated as set. So my additional variables let me know that there was no seconds field.

I was hoping that the new classes would no longer require me to keep my own indicators and I would also be able to parse something like 2020-10-01T04:55. I could not, but I could parse a full time stamp. So if I do that and truncate, can I indicate that the truncated fields are not supported? That way I wont use a value of 0 in the seconds.

Comment: Would it be possible to you to use Optional? See: https://mkyong.com/java8/java-8-optional-in-depth/

Comment: BrianReinhold - Probably, I didn't understand your question and therefore I've deleted my answer. You have mentioned, `Right now in the Calendar case I have to add numerous methods to a class to indicate that.` I will try to answer your question if you can post your code which you have already tried.